# Ising anyon (or Ising topological order) from spin lattice model

Tags: topological-order, anyons

It is well-know that Kitaev’s honeycomb lattice model can give rise to non-abelian Ising anyon.

I am wondering, is there another spin-lattice model in two spatial dimension that also can host Ising anyon (or equivalently, Ising topological order)?

Comment: I have a 1991 paper (Non-Abelian Statistics in the FQH states 
Phys. Rev. Lett. 66, 802), that proposed a spin liquid with SU(2) level 2 non-abelian topological order, which contains  non-abelian Ising anyon.